# v.what.rast cannot find points map layer

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0

I would like to apply [v.what.rast](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.what.rast.html) with a particular points map. Trying the straightforward way, the module complains there is no layer 1 (the default) in the points map:

```
> v.what.rast map=debug_interpol_points_corr raster=weights column='value'
ERROR: Database connection not defined for layer 1
```

First the sanity check, there is indeed a layer 1 in this map:

```
> v.category input=debug_interpol_points_corr option=report
Layer: 1
type       count        min        max
point         30          1         30
line           0          0          0
boundary       0          0          0
centroid       0          0          0
area           0          0          0
face           0          0          0
kernel         0          0          0
all           30          1         30
```

Trying a different approach, with the `-1` layer number to force the module to use all the layers in the map:

```
> v.what.rast map=debug_interpol_points_corr raster=weights column='value' layer=-1
ERROR: Database connection not defined for layer -1
```

What is this module exactly looking for? Or is this a bug?

**Update**: This is the output from `v.db.connect`:

```
> v.db.connect -p map=debug_interpol_points_corr
Vector map <debug_interpol_points_corr> is connected by:
layer <2/debug_interpol_area_points_2> table <debug_interpol_points_corr> in database </home/desouslu/EAWAG/Projects/RasterStitching/grass/Luzern/Merging03/sqlite/sqlite.db> through driver <sqlite> with key <cat>
```

Is there anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is well upstream of `v.what.to.rast`. The input points map was itself produced with [`v.to.points`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.to.points.html) a module that works in a idiosyncratic way. As the `v.db.connect` command shows in the question the output features are attached to layer 2, not the default layer.

```
> v.db.connect -p map=debug_interpol_points_corr
Vector map <debug_interpol_points_corr> is connected by:
layer <2/debug_interpol_area_points_2> table <debug_interpol_points_corr> in database </home/desouslu/EAWAG/Projects/RasterStitching/grass/Luzern/Merging03/sqlite/sqlite.db> through driver <sqlite> with key <cat>
```

In order to use this map as input to other modules, the simplest way is to move the features produce by `v.to.points` to layer 1. This can be achieved with `v.category`:

```
> v.category input=debug_interpol_points_corr output=debug_interpol_points_corr_1 option=chlayer layer=2,1
WARNING: Database connection and attribute tables for concerned layers are
         not changed
Processing features...
Copying attribute table(s)...
Building topology for vector map <debug_interpol_points_corr_1@small>...
Registering primitives...
30 primitives registered
30 vertices registered
Building areas...
 100%
0 areas built
0 isles built
Attaching islands...
Attaching centroids...
 100%
Number of nodes: 0
Number of primitives: 30
Number of points: 30
Number of lines: 0
Number of boundaries: 0
Number of centroids: 0
Number of areas: 0
Number of isles: 0
v.category complete. 30 features modified.
```

Now, pay attention to the warning message: the attribute tables are left unchanged. It took me a while to understand what this actually means: no attribute table is linked to layer 1. And since layer 2 was removed, there is no longer an attribute linked to this map. From this points onwards it is pretty much impossible to use this layer as input to any module. That was the case with `v.what.rast`.

The solution is therefore to re-link the attribute table to this map, using `v.db.connect`:

```
> v.db.connect map=debug_interpol_points_corr_1 table=debug_interpol_points_corr_1 layer=1 -o
The table <debug_interpol_points_corr_1> is now part of vector map
<debug_interpol_points_corr_1> and may be deleted or overwritten by GRASS
modules
Select privileges were granted on the table
```

Note that layer 1 must be stated specifically and that the command must be used in overwrite mode (`-o` flag).

Finally, `v.what.rast` can be applied:

```
> v.what.rast map=debug_interpol_points_corr_1 raster=weights column='value'
WARNING: Raster type is float and column type is integer, some data lost!!
Reading features from vector map...
WARNING: 6 points outside current region were skipped
Update vector attributes...
 100%
v.what.rast complete. 24 records updated.
```

Answer (score 1):

To check a database connection, please use "[v.db.connect](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.db.connect.html)". You used "v.category" but that basically checks things at geometry level but not at attribute table level.

For details, please see e.g. [The concept of layers](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Vector_Database_Management#The_concept_of_layers) in the GRASS GIS Wiki.